# How can I force dependent project to install nuget package used in dependency?

Tags: nuget

I developed a nuget package "nuget_X" installed on a project "project_1".

I have a second project "project_2" that reference "project_1".

If "project_1" is published as nuget package "nuget_1", I can force "project_2" to reference "nuget_X" by declaring "nuget_X" as dependency of "nuget_1"

But "project_1" is referenced as "ProjectReference". So, how can I configure "nuget_X" or "project_1" to force "project_2" to install "nuget_X"?

Comment: Are you working with packages.config or `PackageReference` based tooling? last one should give you this behaviour by default

Comment: See http://blog.nuget.org/20170316/NuGet-now-fully-integrated-into-MSBuild.html, section "What about other project types that are not .NET Core?"

Comment: @MartinUllrich Thank you, it seems to be exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

PackageReference on Visual Studio 2017 don't allow to force nuget of dependency to be installed when using ProjectReference. But it allow to produce an acceptable equivalent result. for more details, see comments.